# Varnish is running but don't see varnish in the response header

Tags: magento2.3, varnish

I have set up Varnish and confirm it's running in the server.

In the frontend browser response header shows this:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 46
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 37639
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 00:28:31 GMT
Expires: -1
Grace: none
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

I don't see any varnish related responses.

Is varnish working at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see configuration file:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish6.vcl#L193

probably headers your are looking for just not set or unset.

you have some of them:

```
Age: 46
Grace: none
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT
```

Comment: On the first run (any URL), it shows `X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS` and `Age: 0`. And when refreshed that URL then it shows `HIT`. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: yes. `< 0` miss cache |  `> 0` hit cache

Comment: Why does it miss in the first run? Any idea?

Comment: because there are no any cache created yet, you need to send page request before cache created.